# Does every linear operator $T$ in $L(V)$ has at least an invariant subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider that $\mathcal{L}(T)$ represents the space of all linear transformations from $\mathbb{V}$ to $\mathbb{V}$.

I want to know if there always exist at least an invariant subspace. I think actually yes because the kernel of a linear transformation is an invariant subspace. I'm I correct?

Comment: Sometimes the kernel is dimension 0. Are you okay with an invariant subspace being 0-dimensional?

Comment: For rotations in the plane other than the identity and the half circle the only invariant subspaces are the origin and the whole space. These are always invariant but may be the only such subspaces.

Comment: Assuming you mean "proper nontrivial invariant subspace", the answer depends on the field and the dimension of $V$. It would be clearly false for $\dim(V)=1$; for $\dim(V)\gt 1$ but finite over an algebraically closed field, the answer is "yes". Over $\mathbb{R}$ it is true for  finite dimensional spaces of odd dimension greater than $1$.

Comment: And for Hilbert spaces and closed subspaces, it is an [open problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_subspace_problem).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Over $\Bbb R$, it is true for finite dimensional spaces of *any* dimension greater than $1$; we can always find an invariant subspace with dimension at most $2$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann: You are (almost) right: you also need to exclude dimension $2$, which may lack *proper* nontrivial invariant subspaces.

Comment: In general, if the characteristic polynomial of $T$ has an irreducible factor of degree $d$ then $T$ will have an invariant subspace of dimension $d$. This follows from the generalized Jordan form over an arbitrary field. Over $\mathbb{C}$, since any polynomial has a linear factor it implies that any endomorphism on $V$ with $\dim V > 1$ will have a non-trivial invariant subspace. Over $\mathbb{R}$ you might have quadratic irreducible factors so as long as $\dim V > 2$, you're guaranteed to have a non-trivial invariant subspace.